# Typescript - Type inference from configuration objects

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm trying to bind an enum type to a named set of properties (`config` and `result`). The type of each config and result can vary, but I would like to use typescript to infer the types. The following is as close as I could get but there are a few things I would like to change.

```
export type EffectConfigs = {
    [EffectType.Damage]: IDamageEffectConfig;
    [EffectType.Heal]: IHealEffectConfig;
    [EffectType.Haste]: IHasteEffectConfig;
}

export type EffectResults = {
    [EffectType.Damage]: IDamageEffectResult;
    [EffectType.Heal]: IHealEffectResult;
    [EffectType.Haste]: IHasteEffectResult;
}

export type EffectConfigResults = {
    [key in EffectType]: {
        config: EffectConfigs[key],
        result: EffectResults[key],
    }
}

export type EffectHandler<
    Type extends EffectType,
    ConfigResults extends EffectConfigResults,
    Config extends Pick<ConfigResults[Type], 'config'>,
    Result extends Pick<ConfigResults[Type], 'result'>,
> = (config: Config) => (
    caster: IAdventureUserCharacterState | IAdventureMonster,
    activeCharacters: IAdventureUserCharacterState[],
    currentMonster: IAdventureMonster
) => Promise<Result>
```

1. Change the type of `Type` to `extend keyof ConfigResults`.

```
export type EffectHandler<
    ConfigResults extends EffectConfigResults,
    Type extends keyof ConfigResults,
    Config extends Pick<ConfigResults[Type], 'config'>,
    Result extends Pick<ConfigResults[Type], 'result'>,
> = ...
```

However, this give the error:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof ConfigResults[string]'`

2. I'm also not sure if there is a cleaner way to define the `Config` and `Result` types without picking from ConfigResults.

The intended usage in the end is as follows, although I would like to use `EffectConfigResults` again here instead of `EffectConfigs`:

```
const effectHandler = <Type extends keyof EffectConfigs>(effect: EffectConfigs[Type]) => {
    if (effect.type in effectHandlers) {
        return effectHandlers[effect.type](effect);
    }

    throw new Error('effect handler not implemented');
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NdjayW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.